# How can "I don't know if you can tell or not, but..." be used in spoken English?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions

I've just come across that phrase

> I don't know if you can tell or not, but...

Would you tell me what it means and how I can use it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means

> I am not sure if you notice something

Example:

> I don't know if you can tell or not, Rose has been pretty upset
>   recently.

it means that I think Rose has been pretty upset and I am curious if you have noticed the same thing about her.

Also pretty good explanation [here](https://www.speakenglishwithvanessa.com/can-you-tell/#.XH9v5YgzaUk)